# Why the check on e?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am very new to Js and JQuery in general and basically i was just going through the code of [carasoul.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js) and came across the below line of code ::

```
Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {

    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)

    }
```

I have been debugging this plugin for a while to understand how the Jquery carousel works .

now if you have a closer look at the lines of code above , you'll see the below line of code ::

```
  e || (this.paused = true)
```

I understand that this line of code actually makes use of ternary operators and short circuiting , i managed to get my heaad around that , but what i don't understand is that why the check on `e` ?

i totally miss the point of the check on `e` , why that perticular check ? i console.logged and i see that it is false most of the time but , why the check ? can somebody explain explain please ?

Comment: This doesn't actually use the ternary operator. But this is basically the same as doing `if (!e) { this.paused = true; }`

Comment: @MikeC i totally understood that part :) but thats not my queestion

Comment: they are seeing if `!e`...`e` in a parameter...so we'd need to see where this is called from to know what `e` is used for.

Comment: Probably because that method might not only be called from an event handler, but in some situations also directly – and then no `event` object might get passed to it.

Comment: one reason i asked this question is , i see this exact same `e || (this.paused = true)` , in alot of comtemporary JS , and i always wonder why ? why the check on `e` ??

Comment: @CBroe Thanks ! i guess thats my answer !

Comment: @TenaliRaman Maybe you saw `e = e || window.event`. This was needed on old IE, which provided events as `window.event` instead of passing them as an arguments. So it was used everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above by @CBroe, this is a check for an event object inside an event handler. It looks like you can also call those methods directly and thus no event object is passed into the function and a default value to some object member is set.

It's hard to say where and why this is used without knowing the whole source code.